# Stuck on lvl 3, VIM Adventures (first maze)

Tags: vim-adventures

After I get the "x", I don't know what to do in the first maze, if I use "b", I just receive this message:

[image: first maze lvl 3]

Really don't know what to do =s (and "x", "w" and "e" don't work either)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your very close. **Your currently pressing 'b', but you need to enter the uppercase 'B'.** This matches uppercase, instead, and moves you to the 'W' in WORD.

In other words, what your doing will work, if you have caps-lock on.

This is why 'b' attempts to take you to the end of WORD, even though b takes you to the beginning, not the end. There must be a lower case letter, under the rock, and therefore it is the start of a lowercase word.

Its paramount to recognise these differences, if you continue with the game. The difference between lower case and upper case is far more important, in regards to code, as it makes the difference on if something will work correctly or not.

Comment: ohh, now I figured out when they say that "word" is different from "WORD". Thank you so much!

Comment: I will warn you, IIRC, unless you bought the game, solving that puzzle is pretty anti-climatic

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing now. xD

Comment: A total scam?  Creative people need to make a living.  $25 is nothing compared to the hours it took to create this amazing teaching tool.